# Как получить новый фрейм групируя по двум колонкам?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

```
0      name1      1256           механическая
1      name1      1310          электрическая
2      name1      1221   Механическая поломка
3      name1       432           механическая
4      name2      3530          электрическая 
5      name2       291  Электрическая поломка
6      name2      1277   Механическая поломка
7      name3       309   Механическая поломка
8      name3       741          электрическая 
9      name3       501  Электрическая поломка
```

получить такой:

```
name1      2909            механическая
name1      1310           электрическая
name2      3821           электрическая
name2      1277            механическая
.......................................
```

В фрейме данных могут попадаться разные причины: `Электрическая поломка` и `электрическая`, также с `механической`. Но посути это одно и тоже.

Пробовал так

```
new_df.groupby(['col1','col3']).col2.sum().sort_values(ascending=True)
```

Но проблема с разным текстом в 3 колонки. Как быть?

Comment: берете первое слово из третьего столбца и вуаля ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

как-то так:

```
In [146]: df.assign(x=df["desc"].str.lower().str.split().str[0]).groupby(["name", "x"])["val"].sum().reset_index()
Out[146]:
    name              x   val
0  name1   механическая  2909
1  name1  электрическая  1310
2  name2   механическая  1277
3  name2  электрическая  3821
4  name3   механическая   309
5  name3  электрическая  1242
```

Comment: как-то не привычно видеть такие вещи в 1 строчку)) думал о циклах и куче всего другого а тут..

Comment: @Вадим, 95% вещей в Pandas делаются однострочниками ;)

Comment: @Вадим Циклы - зло, никогда не используйте циклы с `Pandas`, это медленно и неэффективно )

Comment: @CrazyElf только начал пробовать `pandas` раньше просто после выполнения запроса из бд циклами все делал. Сейчас решил попробовать запрос сразу в датафрейм и потом дальше работать, так вот не привычно теперь